# Why is <div /> not treated the same as <div></div>

Tags: html, css

I was just testing this and in both IE8 & Chrome I see the same thing, empty (styled) divs are rendered differently depending which way you do it. It annoys me because the former seems so much neater.

Why?

**EDIT**: thanks for the clarifications on XHTML Vs HTML. Currently I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>Test</title>
```

What is a better choice? I'd prefer XHTML as I believe it's a bit nicer.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're comparing to a  `<div></div>` (no whitespace between the tags)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In XHTML (served with `Content-Type` of `application/xhtml+xml`), `<div />` would indeed work. But in HTML mode (`text/html`), then no; HTML is not XML, and XML empty tag syntax is not recognised.

Comment: And to add to what Chris wrote, you can specify a doctype of xhtml (instead of html) in your html page as described here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp. The browser should take the doctype into account when rendering the page.

Comment: It actually doesn't use the doctype when deciding how to render the page (well, whether or not to render as xml). It uses the server's reported content-type. Serving as application/xml+xhtml is a mistake in general, so you should use an html doctype and html syntax. See http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml

Comment: Problem is, XTML served as `text/html` is nothing more than **invalid HTML markup**, and it can't be served as `application/xml+html` since IE does not support it

Answer (score 6):

`<div />` is invalid markup. Since a div can't be self closing (it would just render an empty div), some browsers might render it differently. The [HTML 4.01 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4) state that divs (and spans) have to have both a start and end tag.

Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411182/is-there-a-difference-between-div-and-div-div).

Answer (score 5):

`XHTML` and `HTML` work differently.

In `XHTML` the 2 are identical and are semantically no different.

In plain `HTML`, you cannot self close tags.  And making your tags self close is not bad, it just doesn't make a difference.  The self closures are ignored.

So in plain `HTML` `<div/>` is seen as `<div>` which is never closed.  So you need the `</div>`  to close the tag.

`HTML` browsers have a hardcoded list of self closing tags and handle it for you.