# Uploadify button: Style with CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, uploadify

Is it possible to replace the [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) button (which is a graphic containing up/over/down states) with a simple CSS-styled button?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've been able to come up with a working solution to this. Here's the basic outline:

- Disable the Uploadify button image `buttonImg: " "`
- Make the flash object transparent `wmode:"transparent"`
- Using CSS, position a fake styled `button` or `a` tag behind the flash object
- After initializing Uploadify, set the width and height of the object to match the button behind it

The flash object will shield the button underneath it from mouseover etc. events; so to get 
hover effects, you'll need to take a couple of additional steps:

- Wrap both the button and the upload object in a div
- After initializing Uploadify, set the width and height of the wrapper div to match the button
- You can then use jQuery to handle the `.hover()` events on the wrapper div and apply styles to the button

Putting it all together:

HTML

```
<div class="UploadifyButtonWrapper">
    <a>Upload Files</a>
    <div class="UploadifyObjectWrapper">
       <input type="file" id="Uploadify" name="Uploadify" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.UploadifyButtonWrapper{
    position:relative;
}

/* fake button */
div.UploadifyButtonWrapper a {
    position:absolute; /* relative to UploadifyButtonWrapper */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:10px;
    background:silver;
    color:black;
}

/* pass hover effects to button */
div.UploadifyButtonWrapper a.Hover {
    background:orange;
    color:white;
}

/* position flash button above css button */
div.UploadifyObjectWrapper {
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("input.Uploadify", self).uploadify({
    ...
    buttonImg: " ",
    wmode: "transparent",
    ...
});
var $buttonWrapper = $(".UploadifyButtonWrapper", self);
var $objectWrapper = $(".UploadifyObjectWrapper", self);
var $object = $("object", self);
var $fakeButton = $("a", self);
var width = $fakeButton.outerWidth();
var height = $fakeButton.outerHeight();
$object.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
$buttonWrapper.css("width", width + "px").css("height", height + "px")
$objectWrapper.hover(function() {
    $("a", this).addClass("Hover");
}, function() {
    $("a", this).removeClass("Hover");
});
```

Comment: Good job. you are a better man than I. good luck. My answer will self-delete in 1...2...3....

Comment: You would think it would be possible to trigger the flash through javascript and eliminate the need for this hack.

Comment: Fair warning: Chrome doesn't properly align elements with `position: absolute`; I had to remove `top` and `left` and hard-wire the alignment via `margin-top` and `margin-left`.

Answer (score 32):

I was able to get away with something massively more simple.

xhtml:

```
<div id="uploadify">                  
  Upload Pictures                     
  <div id="uploadify" type="button" />
</div>
```

css:

```
#uploadify object { 
  position:absolute;
  left:0; right:0;  
  width:100%        
}
```

javascript:

```
$("#uploadify>div").uploadify({                     
  'hideButton'   : true                                
  , 'wmode'      : 'transparent'                         
  , 'uploader'   : '/static/uploadify/uploadify.swf'
  , 'script'     : '/static/uploadify.php'          
  , 'folder'     : '/_uploads'                      
  , 'multi'      : true                             
})                                                  

// If you're using jQuery UI.
$("#uploadify").button();
```

Probably a little easier, now that we have `hideButton: true`, not sure if @Herb knew about it.

**UPDATE** I wrote this answer in July of 2010. It's now March of 2013. HTML5 supports multiple file-uploads. Don't use uploadify at all; I don't.

Comment: Great answer!  One minor suggestion, however - Instead of using a compound tag, ('<div id="uploadify" type="button" />') you may want to use a beginning and ending tag ('<div id="uploadify" type="button" ></div>').  Of course, it depends a bit on your doctype if this 'bug' bites you.  Anyway, for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411182/is-there-a-difference-between-div-and-div-div

Comment: This is a great solution, but I found I needed to change <div id="uploadify"> to <div id="uploadify" style="position:relative;"> so that the absolute positioning works as expected.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I don't like that there are two elements with the same id, but I couldn't get anything else to work.

Comment: The alignment isn't right.  Only a small portion of the button is clickable and there's a drastic difference between where the clickable region is on webkit vs mozilla.

Comment: Don't use uploadify. Use HTML5.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just put a Wrapper around it like this:

```
<div class = "uploadWrapper"><input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" /></div>
```

Style it like this:

```
.uploadWrapper object {background-color: red;}
.uploadWrapper object:hover {background-color: blue;}
```

And use the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'hideButton': true,
    'wmode'     : 'transparent',
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/uploads',
    'auto'      : true
  });
});
</script>
```

Works for me ;) 
... and of course you can just use background-images instead of the colors.

Comment: it works, I forgot to set the wmode to transparent. The only change I made was to apply the style directly to the object using the object id, so I didn't need a wrapper

Answer (score 4):

100% working example. Tested in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE6!

HTML:

```
<div id="uploadify-wrapper"><div id="uploadify"></div></div>
<span id="btn">Select files to upload</span>
<div id="uploadify-queue"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#uploadify-wrapper {position:absolute; overflow:hidden}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#uploadify').uploadify({width:1000, height:1000, hideButton:true, wmode:'transparent', queueID:'uploadify-queue', ...);
$('#uploadify-wrapper').width($('#btn').outerWidth()).height($('#btn').outerHeight());
```

Answer (score 2):

reading your answers helped me to solve this one this way

1. First wrap the `<input>` into a `<div class=upload-wrap>`
2. Apply styles to this new wrapper (even :hover)
3. Use the hiddeButton option

**HTML:**

```
<div class="upload-wrap">
<input id="file_upload" type="file" name="file_upload" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.upload-wrap{
    background:#ff0;
    width:133px;
    height:36px;
}
.upload-wrap:hover{
    background:#f00;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'      : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'        : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'folder'        : 'files/images',
    'hideButton'    : true,
    'wmode'     : 'transparent',
    'buttonText'    : 'Upload something'
    'width'         : 133,
    'height'        : 36    
  });
```

This way you're able to style your button, an keep the buttonText option available.  I also had to mess a little bit with the .fla file to get the color and font for my button

Answer (score 2):

A really simple way is to open the file with Flash

You can then change the background colour of the symbol UploadBtn

Save and publish the swf.

Answer (score 2):

Evan was very close, but I needed to make some adjustments for it to work correctly.  Here is what I ended up using:

CSS:

```
#uploadify { 
background: #FF5500; 
border-radius: 5px; 
}

#uploadify:hover { 
background: #B33C00; 
}

#uploadify object { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
}
```

You probably want to fine tune the height here because it does matter.  Also, I aligned it from the top and left rather than left and right from the other example. I left a little styling in there as an example of how you can style the button wrapper.

HTML:

```
<div id="uploadify" style="position: relative;">   
  Upload Screenshots
  <div id="uploadify_button" type="button"></div>
</div>
```

The relative position is important for the absolute positioned button inside.

JavaScript:

```
$("#uploadify_button").uploadify({                     
  'hideButton' : true,                                
  'wmode'      : 'transparent',
  'uploader'   : '/static/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
  'script'     : '/static/uploadify.php',
  'folder'     : '/_uploads',         
  'multi'      : true,
  'width'      : '140',
  'height'     : '25'
});
```

The width and height are very important as they determine the actual clickable region within the button div.  I found that without these it's only clickable in a certain area.

Answer (score 2):

For Uploadify version 3.2.1, You can edit stylesheet file `uploadify.css` in this classes:

- .uploadify-button
- .uploadify:hover .uploadify-button

In my case, I comment all styles of them to remove background and border of button and default button was hide completely.