# How to change the uploadify image

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I am using uploadify for file upload in asp.net. I want to change the file upload name. the default text is browse I want to change it to Audio upload. How can I change the text inside the upload file.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
                'uploader': 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
                'script': 'Upload.ashx',
                'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
                'folder': 'uploads',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': true
            });
        });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to rename the button to something else, then you could use **uploadifySettings**. 
Ref: [uploadifySettings](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/methods/uploadifysettings/) Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483662/uploadify-button-style-with-css)
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your uploadify config.

```
'buttonText'    : 'Audio Upload/or any text',
```