# Uploadify button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I am trying to apply my own style to the uploadify button as suggested here:
[Uploadify button: Style with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483662/uploadify-button-style-with-css)

.js:

```
   <div class="uploadWrapper"><input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" /></div>

 $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'uploader': '/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': '/File/Upload',   
        'cancelImg': '/Scripts/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.htm;*.html;*.txt;*.zip',
        'fileDesc': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.htm;*.html;*.txt;*.zip',
        'auto': true,
        'multi': true,
        'sizeLimit': 1048576,
        'buttonText': 'Upload Files',
        'hideButton': true,
        'wmode': 'transparent',
         //more code here....
```

.css:

```
.uploadWrapper object {background-color: #0099FF;}
```

This works well and I see a Blue colored button that I can click to bring up the file dialog. However, the text on the button is invisible/not set. How can I set the button text?

Comment: have you tried to change the button to an 'a' tag instead of to an 'input' like in the example? www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/buttontext/

Comment: Looks like the uploadify website is down... will try it out in some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {                  
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' .        $timestamp);?>',
                'sernofa'   : '<?php echo $likeString; ?>', 
                'width'    : 300
            },
            'queueSizeLimit' : 1,
            'uploadLimit' : 1,
            'buttonText' : 'Attach File',
            'swf'      : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
            'onQueueComplete' : function(queueData) {
             console.log(queueData);
    }


        });
    });
</script>
```