# Style Uploadify button with css in version 3.2.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, uploadify

First of all, I went through this SO question [Uploadify button: Style with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483662/uploadify-button-style-with-css) , but it's the older version.

In the Uploadify documentation, they show us how to change the button with a png image, my question is, is it possible to style the button in css? If yes, how can it be done in this latest release?

What I done so far,

**HTML and CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .uploadify-button {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .uploadify:hover .uploadify-button {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'buttonImage' : '/uploadify/browse-btn.png',
        'swf'         : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php'
    });
});
```

Its exactly what documentation suggest, Is there any way to Style the Button with css, instead of adding a png image as button image

Comment: Could you add a link to A) the documentation in question and more importantly B) show us the code you already have?

Comment: @yochannah Hi mate, My actual question is, Is that possible, what i have already done was nothing to do with the css styling, its just adding a png path in fn call, as suggested by the documentation, anyway, I'll try to add that also..

Comment: What is not working about it? Modifying the display will be easy if you inspect the classes it has once the other library does all its magic in creating the new DOM elements. You'll just need to know how to access it, but right now you're not showing us anything that isn't working.

Comment: @SobinAugustine You can use `'buttonClass': 'customclassname'`([See docs](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/buttonclass/)) and use that class to target the button. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/oq5p3p6z/). Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @SobinAugustine Are you still looking for an answer? Not sure what you have been looking for. If your uploadify has options for button image set then in CSS you have to set styles with !important. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oq5p3p6z/2/)

Answer (score 2):

### HTML

```
<div class="UploadifyButtonWrapper">
    <a>Upload Files</a>
    <div class="UploadifyObjectWrapper">
       <input type="file" id="Uploadify" name="Uploadify" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.UploadifyButtonWrapper{
    position:relative;
}

/* fake button */
div.UploadifyButtonWrapper a {
    position:absolute; /* relative to UploadifyButtonWrapper */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:10px;
    background:silver;
    color:black;
}

/* pass hover effects to button */
div.UploadifyButtonWrapper a.Hover {
    background:orange;
    color:white;
}

/* position flash button above css button */
div.UploadifyObjectWrapper {
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

### Javascript:

```
$("input.Uploadify", self).uploadify({
    ...
    buttonImg: " ",
    wmode: "transparent",
    ...
});
var $buttonWrapper = $(".UploadifyButtonWrapper", self);
var $objectWrapper = $(".UploadifyObjectWrapper", self);
var $object = $("object", self);
var $fakeButton = $("a", self);
var width = $fakeButton.outerWidth();
var height = $fakeButton.outerHeight();
$object.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
$buttonWrapper.css("width", width + "px").css("height", height + "px")
$objectWrapper.hover(function() {
    $("a", this).addClass("Hover");
}, function() {
    $("a", this).removeClass("Hover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property `hideButton` to `true` and make your own button.

The style must be completely remade.

Also, set `wmode` to `'transparent'` to avoid problems.

Now, you can apply your CSS to the element where it is.

Don't forget to set the properties `width` and `height` to match the dimensions of the button.

---

Other solution is to change the `buttonImage` to a pre-styled png image, using any image editor.