# Uploadifive an image as button

Tags: html, css, uploadifive

I'd like to change the uploadifive uploading button with an image.

I tried many ideas but nothing helped.

```
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="image" src="/images/upload_foto3.jpg" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"/>
```

This is not helped (JS changes this)

So I realised I should change the JS.

Changed this (ln 94):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg">').css({"font-size":f.height+"px",opacity:0,position:"absolute",right:"-3px",top:"-3px","z-index":999})
```

To:

```
<input type="image" src="/images/upload_image.jpg" accept="image/jpeg">').css({"font-size":f.height+"px",opacity:0,position:"absolute",right:"-3px",top:"-3px","z-index":999})
```

This is also not helped. (The image not showed up)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much!!

Update: Thanks for the mentioned topic, but that is only for Uploadify not Uploadifive (this is HTML5 based). It is different.

**Update 2:**  This is the main JS file which is modifing the HTML.: http://pastebin.com/UF2y6SuJ
My highlighted code is at line 94.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploadify button: Style with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483662/uploadify-button-style-with-css)

Comment: Thanks for the mentioned topic, but that is only for Uploadify not Uploadifive (this is HTML5 based). It is different.

Comment: Could you past more code. I mean it will be easier to help you if I can see parent of this input

Comment: Updated my question! Thanks!