# offset() value is not proper in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I specified like this

```
<div id="Chart1"/>
<div id= "Chart2"/>
```

and on getting the offset top value ($("#Chart2").offset().top) of second div it doesn't consider the pervious div element

Sample link: http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/zcmkbrle

And if I specify like this

```
<div id="Chart1"></div>
<div id= "Chart2"></div>
```

and on getting the offset top value of second div it consider the previous one.

Sample link: http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/0fzplhdm

I am using jQuery version 2.1.4.

So suggest an idea to rectify this. I need to get the exact offset value of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div />` is not valid HTML. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753748/div-div-vs-div#answer-6753769) SO answer for further details..

And in your case, the second example shows the exact offset. For confirmation, use `Web Development Tool`.

Answer (score 0):

`<div/>` is not valid HTML so can you please use `</div` instead of `/>`.

I have modified the sample. You can find it here:

http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/mjzicdbf