# Is it allowed to have a self-closing div tag in an html document?

Tags: html

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) refers specifically to a script tag. I think it applies also to a div, but I just want to make sure. Is this legal html or not?

`<div/>`

Comment: in HTML, anything goes. In strict XHTML documents, no, it's not allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [<div></div> vs <div />](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753748/div-div-vs-div), [Is there a difference between <div /> and <div></div>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411182/is-there-a-difference-between-div-and-div-div)

Comment: That's invalid Markup, you will have to use the closing tag with &lt;div&gt; In any case there is absolutely useless to have a div close without anything in it :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it isn't legal HTML.

The `div` element is not described as an `EMPTY` element in the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) (4.01).

The definition doesn't have `EMPTY`:

```
<!ELEMENT DIV - - (%flow;)*            -- generic language/style container -->
<!ATTLIST DIV
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  %reserved;                           -- reserved for possible future use --
  >
```

Contrast with the definition for `HR`:

```
<!ELEMENT HR - O EMPTY -- horizontal rule -->
<!ATTLIST HR
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  >
```