# Two div after render page second div nested in first div

Tags: html

If i insert two closed empty div , i get one nested in another after render.

Source:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="up"/> 
    <div id="prop"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Render:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="up">
        <div id="prop"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i insert first block as opening and closing tag, this is not happen:

Source:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="up"> </div>
    <div id="prop"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Render:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="up"></div>
    <div id="prop"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it OK to use a self closing DIV tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971716/is-it-ok-to-use-a-self-closing-div-tag) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757523/is-it-allowed-to-have-a-self-closing-div-tag-in-an-html-document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is HTML not XML.

HTML does not support the closing of a TAG i.e. `<div id=up"/>`.

A well formatted Empty div should be as follows:

```
<div id="up"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you should always close your `div` tags?..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

> Tag omission: None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the difference between HTML and XML!

HTML does **not** allow all tag-types to be closed "immediately", read this article for more info: http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/

Maybe what you wanna use is XHTML for behaviour and syntax you would expect from XML.